# Connect to SQL server through other server

Tags: sql-server

In the image blow you see the situation of a project i'm working on.

[image]

On the app server runs Apache for the web app code. The database is an SQL server 2019 which runs on a computer of the client. There is a firewall in the company with a rule. This rule is dat only the IP address of the APP server can connect to the SQL server on port 9988. All other connections to this server:port are blocked.

Everytime the client calls, I have to take over the screen of the clients computer to start SQL server management to view some tables or other stuff. It's not always the right time to do this. And I only need to view the tables/queries/...

Is there a way that I can connect to this SQL server through the APP server from my computer? That the APP server acts like a middle man?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by installing nginx to act as a proxy on the application server. I've used follow configuration:

https://dev.to/jordonr/reverse-proxy-ms-sql-with-nginx-3e90

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.